# 2002 Chevy Silverado CV Boot

Tags: chevrolet, silverado, cv-boot

I was recently driving down a major 3 lane highway at about 70/mph at night in the middle lane. A large landscaping boulder was bouncing towards me and caused major damage to the y-pipe assembly and now has to be replaced. Could the CV boot have been broken by this impact as well? It was leaking slightly previously but liquid gushed out after this accident.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I really doubt the rock itself would have done this directly, but the jarring of the vehicle by the rock might have, especially considering it was leaking to begin with. The axle shaft is fairly well protected by the surrounding suspension pieces, on both sides. If the boot was split in the first place, it needed to be fixed.